# Foundation-Rails not loading CSS

Tags: zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use Foundation in a pre-existing Rails 5 project, but none of the Foundation styling is actually loading.

I've been through the following steps:

1. Add `gem 'foundation-rails'` to the Gemfile
2. Bundle
3. Run `rails g foundation:install` from the command line, overriding application.html.erb (then pasting back the deleted codes, without overwriting any of the new lines)
4. Rename application.css to application.scss, since (inside the original multiline comment) I'm running `*= require foundation_and_overrides`
5. Restart server, reload pages with some foundation-specific html added, eg, in application.html.erb:

   ```
     <div class="row">
       <div class="large-4 columns">
         Testing columns
       </div>
       <div class="large-8 columns">
         <%= yield %>
       </div>
     </div>
   ```

But the layout is unchanged (ie, splodged into the top-left of the page).

I've checked that the foundation_and_overrides.scss file is getting successfully loaded by adding some test styles in there which are getting picked up - but nothing is coming through that I haven't added myself.

What might I be doing wrong? (I realise I haven't included much code in here, because I'm not sure where the error might be, so I don't want to do a huge code dump).

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename that file to application.scss and add `@import "foundation_and_overrides";`
and in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add `//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and the thing that fixed it for me was overriding the conflicted files. If you run `rails g foundation:install` and it gives you the option to override the conflicting file (foundation_and_overrides.scss), accept it. This will load in the new file and once you restart your server, you should be good to go. Bare in mind however, this will override both foundation_and_overrides.scss and application.html.erb.

My problem stemmed from the fact that I was trying to use the same old files I was using with Rails 4, and for whatever reason, it broke when I upgraded to Rails 5.

So to summarize quickly:

1. Repeat steps 1-3 you listed above
2. Change application.css to application.scss
3. When prompted, override the conflicted files
4. Restart your server